# If one table can provide the info we need, do I need to join another table

Tags: c#, join, azure-data-explorer

I have two tables, table1 has a foreign key of table2. I want to get some info from table1 including a column which both table1 and table2 have. Should I join these two table to get the info?
For example:
I have two tables Course and Student, such as below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEhBh.png)

```
Solution1:

Course
|project CourseId, CouseName, StudentName, StudentId

Solution2:
Course
| project CourseId, CourseName, StudentName
| join Student
on $left.StudentId == $right.StudentId
| project CourseId, CourseName, StudentName
```

To get the CourseId, CourseName and StudentName, which solution is correct? Is it a good practice to pick solution2?

Please ignore the table design. It is just an example. The issue is coming from a real project that we need a query from one table which contains a foreign id and common column from other table. The query should give the common column back. Is it necessary that join the second table to get the common column?

Comment: Why is there a student name in the course table? Or a student id for that matter. Should there be a many to many relationship between course and student?

Comment: StudentName is violating 2nd normal form

Answer (score 1):

Course table should not have Student name, it’s redundant data. And yes you can use inner join or left join on student id. Just bear in mind with the given information provided by you, the case where student id can be or cannot be null in course table.

Comment: They are example. But yes, the real tables we used in real world contain duplicate columns. I'm wondering which solution should be better since we can get whatever we need from one table. Join works, but is it necessary?

Comment: Yes. Because you are working in relational database

Answer (score 0):

I believe the concept of join should only be used when we need data from 2 or more tables. If you have all the required data in a single table, why you need a join. If were you, I will surely move forward with first solution. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't want to join but I was asked to join. I'm confused why we have to join since we can get whatever we want from one table

Answer (score 0):

Your tables do not follow those three normalization forms.

[image]

This is how entities and relationships should be organized if we are talking about the common scenario of designing a database for a school or something something similar to this.

There is a Many to Many relationship between Courses and Students, which allows us to associate N students with one course, and M courses with one student (one course can be attended by many students, and one student can attend many courses).

Also, this design follows the 3rd Normalization Form.

[Learn more about normalization forms](https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html)

[Learn more about Many to Many relationships](https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/18/fmp/en/index.html#page/FMP_Help/many-to-many-relationships.html)